# How I can automatically read and post from our own API?

Tags: wordpress

we have our own api and now my task is to read the api and pro-grammatically add the post that include images to our wordpress single page site. 
I am completely newbie in wordpress what should I do?

Comment: You can use the WordPress REST API to read and update the post. It is located at htttps://yoursite.com/wp-json   https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/wordpress-rest-api/

Comment: but I want to add new post with images